# Binding oil to glucose in candy

Tags: candy, mixing

I'm trying to mix (coconut) oil into glucose using sunflower lecithin as an emulsifying agent, this is being mixed into a candy (vegan) mix that consists mainly of glucose syrup, pectin, colouring and flavourings. I'm not too sure on the exact process and can't find much information online. The oil is heated and mixed with the lecithin and then mixed in with the hot candy mix (at around 220 F) but this is not mixing at all. Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What kind of candy is this? The product list sounds unusual, is it supposed to imitate a helva? Where did you get the recipe from?

Comment: No, it is more an experiment. I have CBD oil and am making my own edibles. They are too expensive to buy for me and I'd like to take it this way! It comes in oil form and the presence of more oil in the edible helps with the uptake so better to have it in the recipe!